# CSS Spritesheet movement transition. Ease without sliding through the background image

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, transition, css-sprites

It's somewhat hard to explain because it's a mouthful but I'll try to give you the context as best as I can.

I have a little character, facing north, south, east, and west, on a CSS sprite sheet. In my game. you can control his movements with WASD, causing him to visibly move X amount of pixels up, down, left, or right. Depending on that direction, the CSS sprite changes to accommodate accordingly so that he's always "facing" the direction he's travelling.

My problem is that I want to use the CSS transition property, but when I do so, it causes the movement I want however it scrolls through the CSS sprite, which I do not want.

My question is, what CSS property controls the pixel movement on the screen, because setting it to "All" transitions everything, including the background position which I do not want.

I have the following CSS code:

```
.player {
    background: url(character.png) no-repeat top left;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}

.player.playerFront {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.player.playerBack {
    background-position: -48px 0;
}

.player.playerLeft {
    background-position: -96px 0;
}

.player.playerRight {
    background-position: -144px 0;
}
```

Javascript:

```
player.className = 'player playerRight';
player.style.left = parseInt(player.style.left) + 48 + 'px'; // Example of the JS when the player moves right
```

I've tried a variety of possibilities... none of which have worked. Everything on StackOverflow and online only talk about animation or hover effects and don't apply to my specific problem.

Comment: Unclear what you’re asking. _“what CSS property controls the pixel movement on the screen”_ – I only see you moving the player object via the left property, but that has very little to do with the background image. You can either transition the change of a CSS property, or you don’t. If you transition the background position, then the effect you are seeing is to be expected. If you don’t want it, then don’t transition that property, but be specific about the wants you _do_ want to transition instead.

Comment: Use [steps()](http://designmodo.com/steps-css-animations/) for this kind of thing.

Comment: CBroe, I'm wanting to transition the moving of the player object WITHOUT the transition of the background image. I'm wondering what determines that other than the generic "All" in the transition.

Comment: Scott Kaye, I looked into steps but I'm not playing an animation, there's only 4 frames that change based on the direction, no animation. I don't know how to implement steps but keep the ease transition for the movement.

Comment: The moving of the player is surely pased on the vertical horizontal `position` on the screen..right? Seems to me you want to animate/transition that...not the image at all.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes I would like to animate/transition specifically that if possible. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Well it seems you are changing the left/right/top/bottom properties...just animate those with JS. AS mentioned in the answer, you can't transition it because it's inline styling being applied as one lump.

Comment: Ah okay, I'll look into the JS animation then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you don't see a smooth transition in movement is that your JS is moving the character in 48px increments. When you set a style like that directly in JS, you won't see it animate because it sets it to the new value immediately - even if you put a `transition` property on it.

**Edit:**
If you only want to transition the position and not the background-position, you'd do it like this:

```
transition-property: top, bottom, left, right; 
transition-duration: 0.25s; 
transition-timing-function: ease;
```

That said, it still won't have an effect if you're using JS to set the style. When you set `style.left += 48px`, it's going to move that 48px all in one go.

Alternatively, you might have an issue with how your spritesheet is set up. Make sure each "sprite area" (ie, each segment of the sheet that might be visible at once) has the sprite centered in it, not against any of the edges. (It might be helpful to make a codepen showing what you've got, if you want more detailed answers.)

Comment: It is already transitioning smoothly with my code. But it also flickers if you change movement direction since it moves to the new background position. I want it to smoothly transition without the CSS sprite change flickering.

Comment: Also, the 48px movement is transitioning the player to another tile piece of the grid, so it's necessary for it to be that distance, and I think it looks too sharp and rigid when it just moves suddenly without transition but then I have my problem when I do the CSS transition

Comment: Yes thank you so much, this is what I was looking for! Sorry if it wasn't clear at first but so glad it works now. (also it does have an effect, your above code makes the movement transition, even with my JS setting the style)